# How To: Dynamic loading of an entire set of <nav></nav> elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-loading

**Background**

I have several web sites that are related to the same business and they share the same server and even disk space. An entire directory tree is linked in via the file system, and the pages show up on all the sharing sites, just fine. However, each site has different, unique market segmentations, branding, contact data, and so forth. To accommodate this, I have already developed fetching the look-and-feel data from the server using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `ActiveXObject()`, as appropriate, and update of various element attributes is done using JavaScript. For example, the business name, contact links, background color and more are provided this way.

**Goal**

As it is, none of the shared pages have any "navigation" to speak of, certainly no menus, but some of the sites do have these on their other pages. I'd like to now add in each site's navigational tools - the menus - to these shared pages. I am sure I can get all the data to the page via the same mechanism I'm already using. The question is: What are the appropriate ways I can "drop this in?" (Without parsing, it'll be a wall-of-text, but that's OK, I don't care, so long as it works.)

I already have a pair of `<nav></nav>` tags in every file, waiting for this eventuality, but now I'm not sure how I do a wholesale plunk of all this stuff right into the page using JavaScript or other on-page technique. ...I'd like to avoid any further "server side" munging of the HTML if I can!

Should I give the `<nav>` an id and then perhaps there's some basic JavaScript syntax I can use to plop this in?

Of course, I already have .css files and so forth, same name, same spot, so that helps. ... TIA!

Comment: Have you "just tried it"? Pulling text from a file via HTTPRequest and dropping it in as `innerHTML` of an element should be pretty easy, if you already have the fetching part working... That said, if you're not limited by older browsers, you may want to look into [HTML imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), which allow you to import chunks of HTML (and even CSS and JavaScript) into your page.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option?

Comment: @TheJim01 HEY, that's the kind of thing I was hoping for insights on! ... I'm game to trying the innerHTML approach. Heck, I already have a generic function that will take any element with an id and update any attribute, AND I already have a generic "get that data from the server" function as well! So, I throw the contents that usually belong inside a <nav> block into it via just setting the "innerHTML"?! SWEET! I'll try it! Meanwhile, I am ignorant about HTML imports - is that easy? Sounds like it...

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Yes, I'm open to using jQuery, but it may not be necessary, if TheJim's hunch is correct. Will try it out in a few minutes.

Comment: If for whatever reason the earlier response doesn't solve your question, try jQuery's load function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @TheJim01 YAY, IT WORKS! ...If you make your comment an answer, I'll mark it correct. .THANK YOU! Meanwhile, I have no idea why some yahoo wants to close this question - was I just supposed to know this or something?! Crazy. If I hadn't asked, I'd have continued to be puzzled. Whoever it was must be proud they're so much more intelligent than the rest of us who have to ask questions. -shrug-

Comment: I'm guessing, but they probably want to close because you asked your question indirectly. Had you asked (or summarized), "Is there a built-in way to inject HTML from another file into my `<nav><nav/>` tags?" there would have been less question about what the question was. Also, you didn't show what you had tried. The best you could expect were blind suggestions (like my comment). Had you already tried `innerHTML` or HTML imports, it would have been a waste of both of our time. I don't even know which of my suggestions helped you... I recommend writing your own answer, as you know the details.